# Can this problem be solved using sum of geometric sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling with this question:

Use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence to evaluate the sums in the following to write them in closed form: $5^3 + 5^4 + 5^5+· · ·+5^k$, where k is any integer with $k \geq 3.$

From the lecture I learned that the geometric sequence start with $i \geq 0$. But for this one $k \geq 3$ so would the formula $\sum^n_{1} r^k=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$ apply here?

Comment: First of all, the formula is $$1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n = \sum_{\color{red}{k=0}}^n r^k = \frac{r^{n+1} - 1}{r-1}.$$  Then, in order to have the summation begin at $~k=3,~$ instead of $~k=0,~$ you subtract out the formula that represents $$1 + r + r^2 = \sum_{k=0}^2 r^k = \frac{r^{2+1} - 1}{r-1}.$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$
With $r=5$ and you subtract $5^2+5^1+5^0$ because those are the missing terms from your series.

Comment: Thank you so much!